# Wordpress add URL var for logged in users only

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

We have cloudflare on our site which can get traffic spikes from 30 user/min - 400 user/min meaning that we need to add some pretty aggressive caching. This means that logged in users will see a chached experience since cloudflare can't tell the difference between logged in users and non-logged in users.

To get around this, when a user is logged in I would like to set a URL Var to the end of the string stat says something like "log.php" or https://url.com/log.php

Log.php could be anything but as long as I can set a filter at cloudflare to accept that anything ending in *.log.php is not a static file.

I have tried a few solutions in the functions file but they don't seem to set the var correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried playing with the permalink structure like adding functions similar to

function reset_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure( '/cats/' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'reset_permalinks' );

Comment: I tried this one
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
  $vars[] = "myvar";
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );